# How to use aggregate function in R to calculate average of same months of different years?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, raster

I have a .csv file with monthly mean data in two columns:

```
Date, Mean
200601, 45
200602, 93
200603, 76
..
..
..
2001005, 54
```

(date format is yyyymm)

I want to calculate average of Jan months of each year i.e.(Jan 2006, Jan 2007..till Jan 2010) and similarly for Feb...till Dec.

I am trying to use aggregate function in R to do so but due to yearmonth date format (not having day), I am getting error. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Use the `substring()` function to create a new vector of the month like: `substring(df$Date, 5, 6)`.  Now you. can aggregate/group on this new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract the *Month* part from the *Date*, then use `aggregate`

```
df$Month <- sub("^\\d{4}", "", df$Date)

aggregate(Mean ~ Month, df, mean)
   Month     Mean
1     01 39.33333
2     02 34.00000
3     03 33.00000
4     04 50.50000
5     05 27.00000
6     06 52.50000
7     07 40.50000
8     08 55.50000
9     09 64.50000
10    10 65.50000
11    11 65.00000
12    12 25.00000
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("200601", "200602", "200603", "200604", 
"200605", "200606", "200607", "200608", "200609", "200610", "200611", 
"200612", "200701", "200702", "200703", "200704", "200705", "200706", 
"200707", "200708", "200709", "200710", "200711", "200712", "200801"
), Mean = c(49L, 65L, 25L, 74L, 18L, 100L, 47L, 24L, 71L, 89L, 
37L, 20L, 26L, 3L, 41L, 27L, 36L, 5L, 34L, 87L, 58L, 42L, 93L, 
30L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I define the .csv file as data in df <- structure(list(Date = because I have many years of data and it is difficult to mention it in the way you mentioned. Kindly help

Comment: To read in your data try `df <- read.csv(“file.csv“, header=T)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should turn your date column into dates instead of numbers.  You can do this with the `lubridate` package.  In this case your format is year followed by month so you could use `ym()` which takes that format and turns it into a date.

Then you could use the `month()` function get each month.  I like using tidyverse, so you could also use `group_by()`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
data <- tibble(
  date = c(200205, 200206, 200305),
  value = c(2,3,4)
)
data
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     date value
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 200205     2
#> 2 200206     3
#> 3 200305     4

data %>% 
  mutate(date = ym(date)) %>% 
  group_by(month = month(date)) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   month   avg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     5     3
#> 2     6     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. But how can I input data mentioned in csv file in date <- tibble ( date  = as I have many years of data in csv file? Kindly help

Comment: there is a function called `read_csv()` that you can use.  Just give it the file path to your csv.  Same as what Andre mentions in his comment